# Cannot change Spring Boot logging level from application.properties but can from logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have a multi-module Spring Boot project and it has  `DEBUG` level logging that need to be changed to `INFO` level. As it uses Spring Boot 1.2.5, I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html), but setting `logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO` in `application.properties` has no effect and we keep getting `DEBUG` messages in the log.

However, providing a `logback.xml` like the one on the above mentioned site and setting the level there works. Even without setting it explicitly, as the `base.xml` that comes with Spring Boot and is included in our `logback.xml` has the root logging level set to `INFO` by default.

Spring Boot uses SLF4J with Logback as default but we do not want to depend on Logback just because of this and we should be able to configure logging level from `application.properties`. The project is configured programatically so `application.properties` does not contain anything else. Both configuration files are in the classpath under `src/main/resources`.

I have tried with `logging.level.*=INFO`, tried different delimiters (`:`, , `=`). I have searched though the project files but have found no traces of existing log configuration.

What can cause that `application.properties` is being ignored/overidden but `logback.xml` is not?

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try if it works on a higher level. Are you sure the properties are read at all ? Try to change something else, server.port for example

Comment: If you use a `logback.xml` i doubt the settings from the `application.properties` will still work. Try removing your `logback.xml` file and only use an `application.properties` one.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry if I was ambiguous. The problem is that when I remove `logback.xml` the `application.properties` won't take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the name of the application.properties file to use with either `spring.config.location` or `spring.config.name` (see [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) for details)

Besides that you can use the `/env` endpoint of [Actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) to see which files are processed by Spring Boot and which values are read from them. This will tell you if there are more configuration file than you provide.

Perhaps a quick check might help: check something in the application.properties, for example `server.port=4711`, then you will know immediately if the file is read or not.

Keep in mind that some logging output gets written before application.properties is read. That means some org.springframework.web messages might be already written before Spring Boot learns that you don't want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `logback.xml` Spring Boot will use `Logback` as primary `LoggingSystem`. Spring Boot has no mandatory logging dependence, except for the commons-logging API.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot set logging in `application.properties` when there is no `logback.xml`. Using the latter is a workaround for setting logging level.